# Lightbox 2 in Joomla

Tags: joomla

How can I get lightbox 2 into Joomla?
And I mean the real one:
http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/
I already have the images, so I just want to add rel="lightbox" to my image link and the lightbox pops up.

Is there an extensions available or do I have to include the script files manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used slimbox and included the script files manually in the header on index.php, load jquery, and use noconflict for the custom script in the header

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an extension that uses Lightbox 2 specifically, but JoomlaWorks has something similar that works very well with Joomla.

http://www.joomlaworks.gr/content/view/51/41/#demos

You can also check the Joomla Extension Directory to see if any use the script you specify:

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=lightbox

Comment: Thanks but I alreay have some images and an automatic image slider shown on my site.  
I just want to add rel="lightbox" the the images links now so the lightbox pops up